# Historical proof of Bézout's theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, math-history, intersection-theory

Bézout's theorem says that given $f, g$ homogeneous polynomials over $\mathbb{CP}^2$ with degrees $n, m$ respectively, the number of intersections of their zero sets is exactly $nm$, counted with multiplicities.

I know of two proofs that can be found in modern references. One uses the more classical machinery of resultants (in which intersection multiplicity is defined as the exponent of a particular term in a particular resultant), and the other uses the more modern machinery of local rings (in which intersection multiplicity is defined as the dimension of a particular vector space).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem) alludes to a third, less rigorous proof that goes somewhat along these lines: The intersection multiplicity of $f$ and $g$ at $p$ can be computed by applying small perturbations to the coefficients of $f$ and $g$, then counting the maximum possible number of intersections in a small neighborhood of $p$. In doing so, we reduce the problem to counting intersections of generic polynomials, which is easy (but I don't see why it's easy).

Apparently, this is Bézout's original proof, so I tried reading a translation of his original book *General Theory of Algebraic Equations*. But I have a difficult time parsing the older language. Is anyone able to help me write down the correct definitions and sketch the basic steps of this argument? Thanks!

Comment: $f, g \in \mathbb{CP}^2$ is somewhat ambiguous notation; I assume you mean $f, g$ are curves rather than points?

Comment: Thanks for correction, edited.

Comment: The "easy" part is taking your polynomials as copies of different lines. You're doing something similar in Schubert's calculus. Perturbing the coefficients lets you, in any case, avoid multiplicities.

Comment: Could be helpful: Keith Kendig, in the book *Conics*   devotes Chapter 11 "A Most Excellent Theorem"  to Bezout's theorem; pages 183-214. The discussion of Bezout with Hassler Whitney is in the dedication, page xii. Written as a conversation and deliberately informal.

Comment: I speak French and would be glad to help re-write the original proof in the modern language, but would you indicate specifically in which section of the book the proof is?